# HDP (2.3): Squirrel (3.7): Phoenix (4.4.0.2.3.0.0-2557): Hbase connection time out

Tags: jdbc, hbase, hortonworks-data-platform, squirrel-sql

We have HDP installed on AWS EC2 Cluster (2 Name Nodes, 3 Data Nodes, and 1 Management Server). In order to use phoenix (4.4.0.2.3.0.0-2557) with Hbase, we have followed basic steps mentioned in Hortonworks documentation.
([Hortonworks-Phoenix Installation Guide](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.1.3/bk_installing_manually_book/content/rpm-chap-phoenix.html))

In order to connect with server, We have used phoenix-client jar with same version as server and written a basic Java driver for connection.

```
Class.forName("org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver").newInstance();
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:phoenix:zookeeper_quorom_server_ip","","");
```

Getting below error after running this program.

> org.apache.phoenix.exception.PhoenixIOException: callTimeout=1200000, callDuration=1237464: 
>       at org.apache.phoenix.util.ServerUtil.parseServerException(ServerUtil.java:108)
>       at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.ensureTableCreated(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:881)
>       at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.createTable(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1215)
>       at org.apache.phoenix.query.DelegateConnectionQueryServices.createTable(DelegateConnectionQueryServices.java:112)
>       at org.apache.phoenix.schema.MetaDataClient.createTableInternal(MetaDataClient.java:1902)
>       at org.apache.phoenix.schema.MetaDataClient.createTable(MetaDataClient.java:744)
>       at org.apache.phoenix.compile.CreateTableCompiler$2.execute(CreateTableCompiler.java:186)
>       at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement$2.call(PhoenixStatement.java:303)
>       at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement$2.call(PhoenixStatement.java:295)
>       at org.apache.phoenix.call.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:53)
>       at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement.executeMutation(PhoenixStatement.java:293)
>       at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement.executeUpdate(PhoenixStatement.java:1236)
>       at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$12.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1893)
>       at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$12.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1862)
>       at org.apache.phoenix.util.PhoenixContextExecutor.call(PhoenixContextExecutor.java:77)
>       at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.init(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1862)
>       at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver.getConnectionQueryServices(PhoenixDriver.java:180)
>       at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.connect(PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.java:132)
>       at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver.connect(PhoenixDriver.java:151)
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
>       at HadoopConnector.main(HadoopConnector.java:17)
>   Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: callTimeout=1200000, callDuration=1237464: 
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:159)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.executeCallable(HBaseAdmin.java:3917)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.getTableDescriptor(HBaseAdmin.java:441)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.getTableDescriptor(HBaseAdmin.java:463)
>       at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.ensureTableCreated(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:815)
>       ... 20 more
>   Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: Can't get connection to ZooKeeper: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation$StubMaker.makeStub(ConnectionManager.java:1533)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation$MasterServiceStubMaker.makeStub(ConnectionManager.java:1553)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getKeepAliveMasterService(ConnectionManager.java:1704)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.MasterCallable.prepare(MasterCallable.java:38)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:124)
>       ... 24 more
>   Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: Can't get connection to ZooKeeper: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.checkIfBaseNodeAvailable(ConnectionManager.java:906)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.access$400(ConnectionManager.java:545)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation$StubMaker.makeStubNoRetries(ConnectionManager.java:1483)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation$StubMaker.makeStub(ConnectionManager.java:1524)
>       ... 28 more
>   Caused by: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase
>       at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:99)
>       at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
>       at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.exists(ZooKeeper.java:1045)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper.exists(RecoverableZooKeeper.java:222)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil.checkExists(ZKUtil.java:541)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.checkIfBaseNodeAvailable(ConnectionManager.java:895)
>       ... 31 more

When I try to configure squirrel ( hbase-phoniex-SQL-client) then I am getting similar timeout exception while connecting.

Also tried pinging my zookeeper quoroum server IP from command prompt then it gives a request timeout error. Not sure what I am doing wrong here.